# Why do I get a compilation error when using the [] operator?

Tags: java

So far I have

```
public static void sort(Collection<Integer> l1){
Iterator<Integer> it = l1.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){ //meant to be for(int i; i<l1.size(); i++)
    if(l1[i] < l1[i+1]){
        l1[i] = l1[i+1];
        l1[i+1] = l1[i];
    }

}
```

I am getting my error in my if statement.

Comment: That is because Java allows the [] operator only for built in arrays, like `new Integer[14]`. Further, `l1` is a collection, which is (unlike a list) not ordered, so sorting it make no sense.
I suggest working through a few basic tutorials for Java first.

Comment: Square-bracket syntax is not applicable for collections in Java. Also, not every collection fits for your task - you need exactly ordered collection. Use list and access elements with [`.get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method instead of square breckets.

Comment: Learn the difference between Array and ArrayList
they are two different things in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several errors in your code:

1. A `Collection` can not be accessed as an array (`[i]` notation). You're already traversing it appropriately with an `Iterator`. Use it to access the values while traversing.
2. Accessing `[i+1]` in that loop the way it has the end condition defined will most probably throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.
3. You mentioned you need to return a new list, but you seem to be trying to rearrange the elements in the very same `l1` `Collection`.
4. Don't know if it's been ommited in your code, but you're referencing an `i` variable without defining, and most important, maintaining its value across the loop iterations. Notice this variable is not necessary since you're already traversing the `Collection` using an iterator.

I'd suggest

1. Iterate over the original `Collection` as you're already doing. Remember to use `iterator.next()` to actually make the `Iterator` go forward and actually retrieve the value.
2. Insert each value into a new list, but not just at the end (with `add(item)`). Look for the position it should go into (for instance iterating it with a `while` or `for` loop) and use [`List#add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) to drop the new element into its place shifting the following elements a position to the right. This way this new `List` will be guaranteed to be always ordered.
3. Read a good java tutorial on Collections and loops, for instance [The Collection Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/collection.html) and [Language Basics: The while statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) from Oracle's Java tutorials could be a good starting point.

Just to give an starting point/skeleton, here's an outline of how it could look like:

```
public static Collection<Integer> sort(Collection<Integer> l1){
    List<Integer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Iterator<Integer> it = l1.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Integer currentValue = it.next();

        // Look into sortedList the position where currentValue should go into
        int pos = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<sortedList.size();i++) { 
             // Compare currentValue with sortedList.get(i) 
             // to know if i is the right position for currentValue. 
             // If it is, assign it to pos
         }
         sortedList.add(pos, currentValue);
     }
     return sortedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the First instance, the comments to date are correct. You cannot use a Collection as though it were an array. If you declare

```
public static void sort(List<Integer> l1)
```

then the `toArray()` method can be used to get array.

Secondly, the statements

```
   l1[i] = l1[i+1];
   l1[i+1] = l1[i];
```

cannot possibly work you'll end up with both elements containing the same value.

Thirdly, I would suggest you read up on the "quicksort" algorithm and implement that... it isn't all that difficult. Here's a link for you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsQuicksort/article.html